# error: SharePoint integration with Yammer

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, yammer

After configuring yammer app whith sharepoint the link becomes available in sharepoint,  but on clicking on the link instead of showing the yammer feed , the following error is displayed -

> Unable to connect to remote webserver.
>
> URL `app-3cd776b7433029.s-1507/Yammer%20App%20for%20SharePoint/Pages/StartPage.aspx?SPHostUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fs%2D1507%3A4444&SPLanguage=en%2DUS&SPClientTag=2&SPProductNumber=15%2E0%2E4420%2E1017&SPAppWebUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fapp%2D3cd776b7433029%`

Comment: Could you check if there are relevant logs in the ULS and event viewer?

Answer (score 1):

Is your farm configured for Apps?  You need to ensure you have DNS configured correctly so that Apps will redirect back to a SharePoint web application.  Also, ensure that the web application you are directing too does not have HostHeaders assigned to it.

Answer (score 1):

I am not to familiar with Yammer, but do your SharePoint credentials match the Yammer credentials?  Whenever you try to access anything outside of SharePoint, like connecting to an external database for example, SharePoint uses the current credentials to gain access.  If these do not match, you of course will not get in.  You might have to configure a new BDC Service.  Go to Central Admin => Application Management => Manage Service Applications and set up a new trusted BDC connection.

Like I said, I am not sure if you need this for Yammer, but I do know you have to set up external connections for SharePoint to be able to allow access. [Here is an artical](http://aspe-it.com/blog/2013/how-to-configure-business-connectivity-service-in-sharepoint-2013/) on how to set it up.